# Pitfalls in designing a coop dialog system

Tags: game-design, multiplayer, dialogue-tree

I like the complex, branching structure of games like visual novels and RPGs like Mass Effect. But I also like multiplayer cooperative games. So I thought, "What if there was a multiplayer dialog system?"

My thoughts on several ways it could work:

- At a decision point, all players put in their vote on what to do. Out of the winning side, randomly pick one of the players who actually "speaks" the line.
- At a decision point, a player is randomly selected to make the decision for the group.
- At a decision point, a player is selected on a cycle to make the decision for the group.
- Award the decision to the player with the most relevant skill set (ie. Rogues get the thiefly dialog options)

Clearly this could get complex. But I still want to explore this idea some.

I worry about balance in a few fundamental ways:

- one player dominates the choice pool (boring for other players)
- the dialog feels forced upon unrelevant players (breaks immersion)
- players get the party into big trouble if they pick poor options, even if the majority of the party would choose a better option (tyranny of the minority)
- a player most often gets outvoted (tyranny of the majority)

Which of my mechanics suggestions best avoid the pitfalls I mentioned? Or is there a better idea I haven't considered? Please also highlight mechanics that could annoy players.

Comment: What scale are you thinking? 2 player co-op, or team-based co-op? It'll affect how unanimous the decision will be, and how much the "dialog system" needs to act as the mediator.

Comment: I think Star Wars: The Old Republic has some kind of co-op dialog system but I don't know how it works. Might be worth looking at.

Comment: This seems fairly discussion-based right now; could you elaborate on the *kinds* of pitfalls (mechanical, technical, et cetera) you are specifically looking for, and perhaps provide some further context with specific scenarios from a project you're working on? Otherwise you may want to ask this in the [chat], which is a better forum for open discussion and feedback.

Comment: I'm thinking generically, so anywhere from 2 to 8 players. I can't see myself making a game with over 4, but it'd be good to hear the changes necessary for being flexible with different player counts.

Comment: Yes, I'll try to make the question more mechanics oriented.

Comment: Okay, does that clarify the question?